# Getting the color of an object an empty collides with?

Tags: animation-nodes, color, bvh

How would I get the color of an object that collides with an empty. In this animation node example I get it's location but I would also like the color that it collides with.[image]

Comment: What defines the color of the mesh?

Comment: The color is defined by a material with a diffuse color in the UI.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. If it is a single diffuse color, won't the intersection color alway be that same color?

Comment: The object can have different faces. Each face could have a different material assigned to it. I would like to know what the color of the face is that the empty hits or if I had some other way of identifying the polygon index that it hit I could use a lookup table .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Moving the empty around gives me the color of the nearest surface once it hits the cube. Nearest surface is based on the objects polygon's center points and material indices. I would have preferred to get the RGB values directly but I can put those in a table later. Here are my nodes.
[image]

Comment: Hey Jim. Please accept your answer if it answers your question.